# CSS / HTML text wrap for webkit

Tags: iphone, html, css, webkit, word-wrap

I am trying to achieve the same effect facebook has with wrapping your status if it's too long.
Try to set your status to something like 300 "A" characters with a webkit user agent. How do they do that?

Yes... I know you can use:
word-wrap: break-word

I googled alot and all these tricks only work if you can set the width in advance, which I cannot.
My width is adjusting to 100% screen size to allow stretching when resizing (landscape).

So to sum this up, how can I achieve text wrap without giving a specific width to the element or a parent element, without using JS, under webkit only browser?

I could notice that FB use this property on the parent container:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box
```

But I was not able to apply this to my case...

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you are looking for,

The trick is the combo of:

```
text-overflow:ellipsis; 
white-space:nowrap; 
overflow:hidden;
```

See this jsfiddle for a demonstration http://jsfiddle.net/bPsav/

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it's done this way with a server side language before given to the front-end. You typically want to stay away from content manipulation when you have such a large user base. There is a new CSS3 property that will do this for you, but it's not widely supported.

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

More info can be found via Google

Comment: the ellipsis will only work if it is one line (no wrap), but they somehow managed to go around this. I'm pretty sure it's done on the client size because when you resize the window the text wrap right there...

Comment: I mean the real problem is to how to set the width on the parent element without using "width: XYZ" in you CSS. Maybe there is some new webkit property that we can use?

Comment: If that's the case it could be done with JavaScript where they would watch the relative width of the widow and would adjust the text accordingly. They do some crazy stuff over at facebook. I would love to sit with them for a few days and learn.